# css stair case in contact form 7

Tags: css, contact-form-7

I have added contact form 7 in word-press website with three different types of input boxes. Following is the CSS of input boxes.

```
.inputbox {
    width: 46%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ffe681;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ff9933;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.inputbox-one {
    width: 14%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ffe681;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ff9933;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.inputbox-two {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ffe681;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ff9933;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

I am experiencing CSS stair case problem and unable to resolve it.

Comment: Do you want these inputs as one per line?

Comment: No. In two columns. for phone number there will be three in a row. Please check the updated url in the bottom.

Comment: why you have extra br tag between the inputs? they are causing the issue.

Comment: check the answer and let me know if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Just remove the `<br>` tags after input fields in your contact form.
These tags are introducing this staircase layout. This is the result.

[image]

Comment: Yes it helped. But for the reference I will mention that word-press contact form 7 is automatically adding these tags. To disable them, I have added define(‘WPCF7_AUTOP’, false); in wp-contact-form-7.php

Comment: As your theme is based on bootstrap, You can also consider using bootstrap form and it's inline input classes.